# ResourceNotFoundException throws when a service layer method test is running

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I'm using Spring Boot and I am trying to create a test.

Actually my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MemberServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MemberServiceImpl memberService;

    @Mock
    MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Mock
    Member member;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getMemberId() {

        Long memberId = 1l;
        Member member = new Member();
        ...
        Mockito.when(memberRepository.findOne(memberId)).thenReturn(member);
        MemberDto memberDto = memberService.getMemberById(memberId);
        ...
    }
```

In my `memberService` class and `getMemberById` method, I do a call to `findOne` method of `memberRepository` class. If no member is found a `ResourceNotFoundException` exception is thrown.

I don't understand why I get this error.
Am I not using the right annotation?

Comment: I know that it's tough for problems like this but is there any way you think you can create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your problem? That would really help.

Comment: For starters, your test code has absolutely nothing to do with Spring, so you can delete all of the class-level annotations: no need to start up Spring Boot if you are just using Mockito to mock all of your components.

Comment: Or perhaps you intended to use `@MockBean` from Spring Boot Test 1.4... which is a totally different thing.

Comment: Please read https://metabroadcast.com/blog/testing-objects-cooperation-with-mockito

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly because I can't just copy and paste all the code to debug, but I believe that you aren't initializing the mocks correctly. Try adding the following method:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

use this
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Answer (score 0):

If Mockito does not found any resource for Id you are passing it will automatically throw `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Because in the line `Mockito.when(memberRepository.findOne(memberId)).thenReturn(member);` you are writing for the mentioned memberId the particular`member` should be returned.

But in actual when you call the method the `member` object is not their, so Mockito throws `ResourceNotFoundException`.

You have to use `@Test(expected = ResourceNotFoundException.class)`.